# SQL Select between mixture of text and numeric

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Not sure if it's possible to do this in SQL but... I'm having difficulty selecting results between certain criteria. I have a column that is a mixture of text and numeric. For example: LOC:05-04-01. I'm wanting to select items between two locations. EG: between LOC:05-04-01 and LOC:05-04-20.

I've tried using the standard BETWEEN statement but it returns an empty result.

```
$loc1 = 'LOC:05-04-01';
$loc2 = 'LOC:05-04-20';
$sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE location BETWEEN ? AND ? ORDER BY location DESC");
$sql->execute([$loc1,$loc2]);
while ($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
echo $row['ID'].': '.$row['location'].'<br>';
}
```

My database is similar to below:

```
ID | Location
1 | LOC:05-04-01
2 | LOC:05-04-02
3 | LOC:05-04-05
4 | LOC:06-04-01
5 | LOC:06-04-02
6 | LOC:06-04-10
```

I'm expecting to see a list of locations out of the above query such as:

```
1: LOC:05-04-01
2: LOC:05-04-02
3: LOC:05-04-05
```

Comment: What is LOC 05-04-01, it might be better to store this information in a different format.

Comment: Your code should work.  What problem do you have?

Comment: @MarkOverton Trust me, if I'd have done this database it wouldn't have been stored like this! Unfortunately I can't change it.

Comment: How do you define that a location is "between" 2 others? Numerical values have a different sort order for strings to numerical data types. For example `10>2`, but `'10'<'2'`. If you are using fixed length numerical resprentations, then the problem is less likely as both `10>2` and `'10'>'02'` are true.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm not getting any error message or results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should do what you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM <table>
WHERE location BETWEEN 'LOC:05-04-01' AND 'LOC:05-04-20'
ORDER BY location DESC;
```

You are doing string comparisons, and the values compare as strings.

You should test this using a direct query on the database.   If this doesn't work, then you might have data in columns that you don't expect -- say the hyphens are really a different character.

If the PHP code does not work, something is going wrong at that level.  You might have an error in your query (say connected to the wrong database).  You might have bad characters in your constants.

Comment: Thanks for that, I've run the query directly on the database and I get the desired results so you're right, it's something to do with the PHP code.